# Combining elements of different length from nested list

Tags: r, list, combinations

The following structure is given:

```
a <- list()
a[[1]] <- list(c(1:3),c(3:8))
a[[2]] <- list(c(2:6),c(7:9),c(18:24))
a[[3]] <- list(c(11:13),c(10:16),c(17:19),c(11:14),c(17:20))
```

That means `a[[1]]` has 2 elements, `a[[2]]` 3 elements and `a[[3]]` 5 elements.

I would like to create all the possible combinations from the elements within a.
So for example `a[[1]][1]` can be combined with `a[[2]][1]`,`a[[2]][2]` and `a[[2]][3]`. All of those results can be combined with `a[[3]][1]`,...,`a[[3]][5]` (All in all it should be 30 combinations). By combining I mean applying `c` to the elements.

I assume this comes down to searching elements at the end of a tree (e.g. if I have A1 or A2 in phase 1, B1 or B2 in phase 2 and C1 or C2 in phase 3, all results would be: A1B1C1, A1B1C2, A1B2C1, A1B2C2, A2B1C1, A2B1C2, A2B2C1, A2B2C2.)

Ok now I know how to do this with a triple nested loop, but what happens if list a becomes larger? I don't know if it can be done otherwise though. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: like `expand.grid(sapply(lengths(a), seq.int))` and do some indexing

Comment: with a n-element top list (in your case `a` has three elements) it is similar to the indexing of a n-dimensional array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `expand.grid {base}` :

```
a <- list()
a[[1]] <- list(c(1:3),c(3:8))
a[[2]] <- list(c(2:6),c(7:9),c(18:24))
a[[3]] <- list(c(11:13),c(10:16),c(17:19),c(11:14),c(17:20))

comb <- expand.grid(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to `expand.grid`, if you are looking for more speed as the lists grow, you can check out `CJ` from the "data.table" package:

The approach would be:

```
library(data.table)
do.call(CJ, a)
```

Here are the first few rows:

```
> head(do.call(CJ, a), 10)
       V1        V2                 V3
 1: 1,2,3 2,3,4,5,6           11,12,13
 2: 1,2,3 2,3,4,5,6 10,11,12,13,14,15,
 3: 1,2,3 2,3,4,5,6           17,18,19
 4: 1,2,3 2,3,4,5,6        11,12,13,14
 5: 1,2,3 2,3,4,5,6        17,18,19,20
 6: 1,2,3     7,8,9           11,12,13
 7: 1,2,3     7,8,9 10,11,12,13,14,15,
 8: 1,2,3     7,8,9           17,18,19
 9: 1,2,3     7,8,9        11,12,13,14
10: 1,2,3     7,8,9        17,18,19,20
```

(The `do.call` approach would also work with `expand.grid`).

---

Quick comparison:

```
a <- list()
a[[1]] <- list(c(1:3),c(3:8))
a[[2]] <- list(c(2:6),c(7:9),c(18:24))
a[[3]] <- list(c(11:13),c(10:16),c(17:19),c(11:14),c(17:20))

## 15 item list
a <- unlist(replicate(5, a, FALSE), recursive = FALSE)

system.time(do.call(expand.grid, a))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   8.020   2.232  10.254 
system.time(do.call(CJ, a))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   2.180   0.828   3.004
```

Comment: Thanks! `data.table` seems to be very powerful. I need to get into it.